# Set border width of a table more slimmer in CSS?

Tags: html, css

```
<table width='100%'  cellpaddin='0' border= '1' cellspacing='0' >
```

This is how I've created a table. Border width seems bold. I couldn't put like 0.5px or something else. Is it possible to reduce it's width anyway?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should collapse the borders using `border-collapse: collapse;`, the `border` which you are setting uses browser default styles which is kinda 3d, you can use [`border-style: solid;`](http://jsfiddle.net/u6T6E/1/) for `table` as well as `td`, consider using the approach below, instead of using attributes, apply the borders using CSS

```
table.class_name {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.class_name td {
   border: 1px solid #aaa;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u6T6E/)

Comment: Beat me to it by a minute, touche, and a fiddle to boot!

Answer (score 1):

Style the td and th element

```
td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

and for no spacing between cells use:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

See jsFiddle Example : http://jsfiddle.net/KbjNr/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use html attributes (width, cellpadding, border, cellspacing) any more.  Use CSS.  A lot of people don't like W3Schools, but I think they'll help you here - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp  .  For a border, you would use something like

```
table { border:1px solid;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use border-collapse on your table tag:

```
table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

This will make sure that your borders aren't doubling up in places where two sides meet. If that still looks too dark, just go with a lighter border-color.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/LXKLW/

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Peter</td>
<td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Lois</td>
<td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
table, td, th
{
border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```